# Create a new page and add contents to it using PHP

Tags: php

This is going to be hard to explain so please ask me for clarification if anything confuses you.

So let's say that I am on `createpage.php`. Within this page, I have the following tasks.

1. Create a new page (file) using PHP via `$file = fopen($pagename . '.php', "x")`.
2. Add premade content to this new page.

The method that I am taking to add new content to the new page is by storing the HTML content code into one variable called `$newpagecontent`. Then, I simply use `fwrite($file, $newpagecontent)`.

The problem is though, that you can't store the whole of HTML/PHP file into $newpagecontent without breaking the double quotes. For example, `$newpagecontent="echo("hello!")"`.

So the question is, is there a better way to add in HTML content to a newly created page? or is there a way to store the HTML code into a variable without breaking the syntax?

Thanks a lot

Comment: jQuery & ajax is the better way

Comment: Use a `\ ` to fix that issue.  `$newpagecontent="echo(\"hello!\");"`

Comment: So the purpose of this `createpage.php` is to make new PHP files?

Comment: @FoolishSeth yep it is to make new PHP files which is basically a new page

Comment: Is the premade content always the same?  Is the premade content all that goes in the new files or are you mixing it up with other variable content?  e.g. (some premade content) (some variable content) (more premade) (more variable) etc.

Comment: @FoolishSeth Good point! In fact, I do have some variable content in the premade content, such as the title of the page etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the contents of the other file that contains the HTML/PHP code, then try `file_get_contents` to read the contents and store it in the variable. Please see the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) of this function for further details.